# How to set style for empty child?

Tags: css, parent-child, margin

I have the following style:

```
<style>
  #area {
    float: left;
  }
  #view {
    font-size: 130px;
  }
  #view * {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
</style>
```

And the following body

```
<textarea id="area" rows="60" cols="60"></textarea>
<div id="view"></div>
```

Javascript is copying text from `#area` into `#view` transforming it from markdown to html. If there is any text there is no problem, we obtain this result.

[image: markdown.png]

But if we type `#` or space we get big vertical space between browser bar and rest of site:

[image: markdown_incorrect.png]

My question is: How to keep content near to browser bar when

```
<div id="view"></div>
```

is changing to

```
<div id="view"><h1></h1></div>
```

Full code is presented on my [github](https://github.com/gustawdaniel/markdown_viewer).

Exemplary site:

> http://176.31.191.131/stack_markdown_example/markdown_viewer/

If you type `#`, site create big vertical space.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I added link to exemplary site.